# Obtain an enum value via an annotation value in Java

Tags: java, enums, annotations

I am attempting to use an annotation string value, associated with enum values, in order to obtain a reference to the associated enum value.

I've ended up getting stuck mid way... At present I have the below development code:

Annotation code:

```java
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation{
    String value();
}
```

Enum code:

```java
public enum MyEnum{
    @MyCustomAnnotation("v1")
    VALUE1,
    @MyCustomAnnotation("v2")
    VALUE2,
    @MyCustomAnnotation("v3")
    VALUE3,
}
```

Making use of the enum annotation:

```java
String matchString = "v1";
MyEnum myEnumToMatch;

// First obtain all available annotation values
for(Annotation annotation : (MyEnum.class).getAnnotations()){
    // Determine whether our String to match on is an annotation value against
    // any of the enum values
    if(((MyCustomAnnotation)annotation).value() == matchString){
        // A matching annotation value has been found
        // I need to obtain a reference to the corrext Enum value based on
            // this annotation value
        for(MyEnum myEnum : MyEnum.values()){
            // Perhaps iterate the enum values and obtain the individual
                    // annotation value - if this matches then assign this as the
                    // value.
            // I can't find a way to do this - any ideas?
            myEnumToMatch = ??
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't really work with `MyEnum.values()` because annotations are attached to code elements, not object instances. You'll have to use reflection to access the static fields of `MyEnum` that store the enum value constants. Also `MyEnum.class.getAnnotations()` will return nothing because the `MyEnum` class itself isn't annotated with anything so the loop won't run.

Comment: Have you actually fired your code up in a debugger to actually poke around the program state and look at what values what's returning?!

Comment: What's the final need?

Comment: @millimoose - annotations can be attached to classes, methods, fields, and even local variables, so not sure what "annotations are attached to code elements, not object instances" means.

Comment: @parsifal They can't be attached to **arbitrary** object instances (like enum values, or say random strings). Only objects that represent code elements carry annotations.

Comment: @millimoose - an enum value isn't an arbitrary object instance. But you've already added an answer that shows that.

Comment: @parsifal There's a difference between the **field** (code element) `MyEnum.VALUE_1`, and the `MyEnum` **object** it points to. The former can be annotated, the latter can't. For a better comparison, consider the local variables `@SomeAnnotation("s1") String s1 = "aaa"; @SomeAnnotation("s2") s2 = s1;` They variables point to the same object, but it's the variables that each hold a different annotation, not the string. (The string itself cannot be annotated.)

Comment: You're using the wrong mechanism for this. If you want a value in the enum, just do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to have a field in the enum, like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1("v1"),
    VALUE2("v2"),
    VALUE3("v3");

    private String displayValue;

    private MyEnum(string s) {
        this.displayValue = s;
    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

Then in your matching loop, you just loop through `MyEnum.values()` and look for the one which has the correct displayValue.

Answer (score 2):

I fully agree with @MichaelMyers that it's better to add a value to the enum, rather than use annotations. However, the code below should help you understand how annotations are attached to enum values.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnno {
    String value();
}

public enum Example {
    @MyAnno("v1")   FOO, 
    @MyAnno("v2")   BAR, 
    @MyAnno("v3")   BAZ
}


public static void main(String[] argv)
throws Exception {
    for (Field field : Example.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
        System.out.println(field.getName());
        for (Annotation anno : field.getAnnotations()) {
            if (anno instanceof MyAnno) {
                MyAnno myAnno = (MyAnno)anno;
                System.out.println("   anno = " + myAnno.value());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Enum constants are regular fields of `enum` classes, so you have to access those via reflection:

```
for (Field enumValue : MyEnum.class.getDeclaredFields()) {
    MyAnnotation annotation = enumValue.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
    if (annotation != null) {
        System.out.printf("Field '%s' is annotated with @MyAnnotation with value '%s'\n",
                enumValue.getName(),
                annotation.value());
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Field '%s' is not annotated with @MyAnnotation\n", enumValue.getName());
    }
}
```

Mind you, this will also include an internal field called `$VALUES` that contains an array with all the enumeration values. You can filter that out using e.g. `if (enumValue.isSynthethic()) { ... }`.